# One byte converting to two when written to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I do not understand why my code is not working.
I am writing some very simple code to write a single byte to a file.

```py
with open("foo.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\x80')
```

As you can see below, it ends up writing two bytes when I only want to write one... Can anybody help?

[image: Writing two bytes to the file when it should only be writing one]

Comment: You're setting the encoding to `utf-8` so it encodes it to `utf-8`.

Comment: @tkausl If I don't, it says "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: did you tried to open file as "wb+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 2 bytes because of UTF-8 takes 2 byte places, if you decode it into UTF-16 you will see 4 bytes. They are more than 1 byte because you write it into UTF structure, not as a byte.

You have to open it in binary mode.

```
with open("foo.txt", "wb+") as f:
    f.write(b'\x80')
```

Comment: Ok, is there a pythonic way to convert `'\x80'` to `b'\x80'`?

Comment: depends on where did you get '\x80' from

Comment: bytes([80]) is the trick It is up to you how to get the 80.